# Is it possible to change where AngularJS looks for variables?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Now, I know this is an off-the-wall question and that there is probably not going to be any API level access for doing this. I also understand that doing this is completely unnecessary. However, the implementation that I am aiming for requires for me to be able to make `{{ variable }}` look inside of the `$scope.object` instead of the `$scope` itself.

For example:

```
Controller($scope) {
    $scope.active = ...;
}
```

In this case you can get the active object through `{{active}}` and any child elements through `{{active.broken}}` however for the sake of humoring me, lets assume that all of the variables I'm ever going to have to obtain is going to be part of that active object. So I'll be typing things like.. (Data not related)

```
{{active.title}}
{{active.author}}
{{active.content}}
```

You could just say "Well why not just move the `title/author/content` into the `$scope` and keep it outside of the `active` object, as that would achieve the desired result of this:

```
{{title}}
{{author}}
{{content}}
```

Well, that's where the problem comes in. This is a controller that is not exposed to my end-user, however the end-user does have a completely mutable object (in this example: `active`) that they can modify. This object has many [optional] listeners and callbacks that are invoked by the application controller when necessary.

The user's that have used my application during testing have commented on what a drag it is to have to type in `active.` before everything in order to get the data they wanted. Considering data from the `$scope` is never rendered to the screen, and only data from `active` is, I was wondering if perhaps there was a way to change where AngularJS looks when parsing/binding data.

Comment: How are you processing user input? Why do your users have to type `active.`?

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to evaluate expressions in a different context than `$scope`, that can be done with the `$parse` service.

```
app.controller("myVm", function($scope, $parse) {
    var vm = $scope;
    vm.active = { a: 5,
                  b: 3
                };

    var.myFn = $parse("a+b");

    vm.total = myFn(vm.active);
    console.log(vm.total);
});
```

The above example shows how to evaluate the expression `a+b` using the properties of the `$scope.active` object.

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6hhob6cr/)

Comment: The goal is to allow users to be able to use data bindings in a child-object of scope without declaring the child objects. In the sandbox that we have set up the $scope is immutable, other than the mutable object `active` which users can use one and two way bindings on, because of this users will display information by typing `{{ active.whatever }}` think of it has a `$scope` inside of $scope that we want to open up without exposing the rest of the $scope... If that makes any sense